# How to close a window in GWT

Tags: gwt, uibinder, gwt2

I was required to put a "Done" button in a GWT Composite (despite already having the close icon), it should simply close the window upon clicking. Unfortunately, I can't find a `.close()` method to implement it. How can it be done?

[image]

I have a UserDialog class that contains a Composite component, which I named UserComposite. UserDialog extends to CustomDialogBox, which extends to DialogBox class:

```
public class UserDialog extends CustomDialogBox {    
    private UserComposite c = new UserComposite();
    // more codes here
    private FlowPanel getFlowPanel() {
        if (p instanceof Panel && c instanceof Composite) {
            p.setSize(WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            p.add(c);
        }
        return p;
    } 
}
```

and then this is my UserComposite

```
public class UserComposite extends Composite {
   // codes here
   @UiHandler("doneButton")
   void onDoneButtonClick(ClickEvent event) {
      this.removeFromParent();
   }
}
```

I tried removeFromParent() but the UserComposite was only removed from parent which resulted to an empty DialogBox.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to hide the dialog, not the composite. One way to do this is to pass a reference to the dialog box to the UserComposite constructor, and then use that reference to call hide() on the dialog. It could be something along these lines:

```
public class UserDialog extends CustomDialogBox {
    private UserComposite c = new UserComposite(this);
    ...
}

public class UserComposite extends Composite {
    private DialogBox parentDialog;

    public UserComposite(DialogBox parentDialog) {
        this.parentDialog = parentDialog;
    }

    @UiHandler("doneButton")
    void onDoneButtonClick(ClickEvent event) {
        parentDialog.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 This is basically how it's done. It can be improved by defining a CloseCallback interface (so the UserComposite doesn't have to know the entire UserDialog class). Or by using MVP.

Comment: Thanks a lot David. I found a way with *removeFromParent()* but I now prefer your solution.

Answer (score 4):

@Mr. Xymon, By window if you mean instance of PopupPanel or instance of any subclass of PopupPanel, you can use the following :

```
popupPanel.hide();
```

Comment: It's an instance of Composite. **public class UserComposite extends Composite {  }**

Comment: @Mr.Xymon Try calling `widget.removeFromParent();`

Comment: I just tried that but it only removed the component, which resulted with an empty DialogBox. I updated my question and added screenshots.

Comment: @Mr.Xymon, that's it. Ultimately it's a DialogBox and DialogBox is a PopupPanel.